# Swiper to position X in React Native / Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

In my current App I have a List of items. If the user clicks on one of these items details should appear. This details should be dispayed in a swiper. So the user can navigate to the details of the next item by swiping left.

Showing the list, the swiper (Modal) and closing the modal swiper is no problem.

But how to "navigate" the swiper to the item, which the user clicks? The data is the same (redux). I don't think, that it's a good idea to set the data of the swiper each time a user clicks on a list item?

Another questions: How to trigger the "navigateToXandShowModal()"-function of the custom component wrapping the swiper? By saving the ref in the parent component? Is this the correct way?